# Priority in java

Tags: java, constructor

Can any one explain me how this output come

```
class Class
{    
    {   
        System.out.println("Instance Initializer block");   
    }

    Class()
    {
       System.out.println("Default Constructor");
    }

    static
    {
        System.out.println("Static Block");
    }

    public static void main(String[] Args) 
    {
        new Class();
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

output:

```
Static Block
Instance Initializer Block
Default Constructor
Hello World
```

Answer (score 4):

The static initializer block is executed first, when the class is initialized, printing `"Static Block"`.

When the instance is created (`new Class()`), first the instance initializer block is executed (printing `"Instance Initializer Block"`) and then the constructor (printing `"Default Constructor"`).

Finally the `println` statement of the main method is executed, printing `"Hello World"`.

Comment: if i remove curly brackets from "Instance Initializer Block" it give me error

Comment: @Manish If you remove the curly braces, it's no longer an instance initializer block. You can't have a statement that doesn't belong to any method or constructor or initializer block.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence is as follows

1. Static initialization block is being ran when JVM (class loader ) loads Class (**static block is called irrespective  of instance creation**)
2. when you try to create the instance 
    2.1 init block is called 
    2.2 then the constructor.
3. At last your print statement